# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: boolean

There is my code, but I don't know why I get this warning:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM third_box ORDER BY id DESC');
                if($query == FALSE)
            {
                die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
                }
                while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                        echo $output['news'].'<br / >';

                }
```

Comment: it seems silly to ask... but i have to anyway. Do you have the code in there to connect to your MySQL server? i.e. `mysql_connect`?

Comment: i have connection to base.

Comment: Are there any rows of data in `third_box` table? does this query run in phpMyAdmin against your database? `SELECT * FROM third_box ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: there are rows of data in tables.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_*` is now officially deprecated. Please use `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Can you try this:

```
<?php

// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM third_box ORDER BY id DESC";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    // fetch associative array
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        // Display
        echo $row['news'] .'<br / >';
    }

    // free result set
    $result->free();
}

// Close Connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```